How to specify -pix_fmt in a ffmpeg preset file?
In my preset file ~/.ffmpeg/hevc_nvenc-1080p.ffpreset I'm able to pass various options such as
profile:v=main10
tune:v=hq

But attempting to pass
pix_fmt:v=p010le

fails with
/home/p/.ffmpeg/hevc_nvenc-1080p.ffpreset: Invalid option or argument: 'pix_fmt:v=p010le
', parsed as 'pix_fmt:v' = 'p010le'
Failed to set value '1080p' for option 'vpre': Invalid argument
Error parsing options for output file +pix_fmt:v.

Is there a way how to pass this option in a preset?
If not, is there a way to tell which options are allowed and which not in presets?
